# AsyncTask responding differently when not on wifi

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am developing an application which gets activated in the background on the basis of a listener.
In the application, I want to capture the current location of the user (address) and store it.

In the code below, the application works absolutely fine when I am connected to wi-fi.
When I am not connected to wi-fi, something happens at the line "address=gps.getAddress();" and post that the variable pendingResponse is set to false. I do not even get the output of second log.d on the console (Log.d("Your Location",address);

getAddress is a simple function which uses latitude and longitude to reverse geocode and get an address.
I am assuming that the call to getAddress is taking a long time to process since I am on a slow internet connection when not on wi-fi and as a result of which I get stuck in this situation.

Can someone please guide me on how to proceed further.

```
private class BgTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {



@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
   gps = new GPSTracker(context);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   String url=params[0];     

   // check GPS location
   if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
       Log.d("Your Location", "latitude:" + gps.getLatitude() + ", longitude: " + gps.getLongitude());
       address=gps.getAddress();
       Log.d("Your Location",address);
       responsePending=true;
   } else {        
       Log.d("Your Location"," Location Not Available");           
   }      

   return "All Done!";
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
   super.onProgressUpdate(values);       
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   super.onPostExecute(result);       
}

}
```

Adding code for getAddress function

```
 public String getAddress(){
   String address="";

   // getting address with geocoder using reverse geocoding
   Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
   try{
   List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(getLatitude(), getLongitude(), 1);
   if (addresses.size() > 0)           
       address=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)+addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);      
   }catch(IOException e){
       ;
   }       
   return address;     
}
```

Comment: What is GPSTracker? I can't find it in the Android API. What does getAddress do? I ask because if `getAddress` is using WiFi for a less precise location rather than the GPS card, maybe its blocking for a long period of time.

Comment: GPSTracker is a class which checks the availability of Network_Provider and GPS_Provider and returns a latitude and longitude based on the most recent location. The results returned by GPSTracker are visible in the first log output where I am displaying latitude and longitude. getAddress does nothing but take the LatLng and reverse geocide to get an address.

Comment: Can you link me to the API for this? I'd like to see the code, or the doc on `getAddress()` here.

Comment: Added code for getAddress

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to debug these kinds of problems:

```
private String mAddress;
private Exception mException = null;

protected void doInBackground(Params... params) {
  try {
    // your stuff; e.g.:
    mAddress = getAddress();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    mException = e;
  }
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void unusedResult) {
  if (mException != null) {
    Log.e(TAG, String.format("Oops: %s", mException), mException);
    throw new RuntimeException(mException);
  }
  // your normal stuff
  ...
}
```

When the exception occurs, your program will force-close and you will get a full stack trace in your logcat.

Another less-convenient way to retrieve exception information from your AsyncTask is to call AsyncTask.get() (less-convenient because people often do not save off a reference to a newly-created-and-executed AsyncTask).

My guess is that your "getAddress" method is throwing a NullPointerException or something.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the way you suggested. When I am trying to find the address with help of Geocoder, I am getting the following exception - java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server. The point which I cannot understand is that it works fine when device is connected to wi-fi. Is it possible that when connected to a slow internet connection, I am not able to get a response from the Geocoder and hence this error. If yes, what can I do to resolve it.

Comment: Since I was not able to get around this issue, I changed my implementation and now instead of the Geocoder class, I am using the google maps api and getting the result as an XML and then parsing it for an address. The new approach is working fine with both wifi and 2g connection.